# How do I migrate Data from one Database Table into another SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm really new at this whole SQL DB migration stuff and I'm ready to learn.

I have 2 different Databases and both of them have a User Table, called `HtUser` in one destination db and `HTUser` in the source db.

I want to create a script that is copying the data from specific columns in the source db that would be `firstName, lastName, email` and in my destination db that would be `FirstName, LastName, Email` and a "special field" `UserName` contains ch + two letters from the `firstName` and three from the `lastName`.

```
    INSERT  INTO HolidayTracker.dbo.HtUser(FirstName,LastName,Email,UserName,AdAccount,AdDomain)
SELECT firstName,lastName,email,'CH'+LEFT(firstName,2)+LEFT(lastName,3),'EUROPE\'+LEFT(firstName,2)+LEFT(lastName,3),''
FROM HolidayTracker.dbo.HTUser U1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM HolidayTracker.dbo.HTUser U2 WHERE U2.FirstName = U1.firstName AND U2.LastName = U1.lastName AND U2.email = U1.Email);








INSERT INTO HolidayTracker.dbo.HtUser(FirstName,LastName,Email,UserName,AdAccount,AdDomain)
SELECT firstName,lastName,email,'CH'+LEFT(firstName,2)+LEFT(lastName,3),'EUROPE\'+LEFT(fistName,2)+LEFT(lastName,3),''
FROM HolidayTracker.dbo.HTUser u1
    LEFT JOIN HolidayTracker.dbo.HtUser u2 ON u1.firstName = u2.FirstName AND u1.lastName = u2.LastName AND u1.email = u2.Email
    WHERE u2.FirstName IS NULL
    AND u2.LastName IS NULL
    AND u2.Email IS NULL;
```

Comment: what have you written so far?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have 2 databases named db1 and db2, this might work.

```
INSERT INTO db2.dbo.HTUser (FirstName, LastName, Email, UserName)
SELECT firstName, lastName, email, 'CH' + LEFT(firstName, 2) + LEFT(lastName, 3) 
FROM db1.dbo.HtUser U1
    LEFT JOIN db2.dbo.HTUser U2 ON U1.firstName = U2.FirstName 
        AND U1.lastName = U2.LastName 
        AND U1.email = U2.Email
WHERE U2.firstName IS NULL
    AND U2.lastName IS NULL
    AND U2.email IS NULL;
```

This version will copy users from db1.dbo.HtUer that do not exist in db2.dbo.HTUser.

And a version using the preferred `NOT EXISTS` (thanks @AaronBertrand!):

```
INSERT INTO db2.dbo.HTUser (FirstName, LastName, Email, UserName)
SELECT firstName, lastName, email, 'CH' + LEFT(firstName, 2) + LEFT(lastName, 3) 
FROM db1.dbo.HtUser U1
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT 1
        FROM db2.dbo.HTUser U2 
        WHERE U2.firstName = U1.FirstName 
            AND U2.lastName = U1.LastName 
            AND U2.email = U1.Email
    );
```

Comment: thanks for wasting you time to answer my question you helped me allot !!

Comment: How could the databases have the same name if they are on the same instance?  Unpossible.

Comment: Sry if I bother you but when I'm executing this query it is just adding the existing  users again

Comment: I've updated my answer to prevent users being copied multiple times.

Comment: +1 but FYI [NOT EXISTS is almost always faster than LEFT JOIN in this scenario](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `INSERT INTO...SELECT` statement on this one.

```
INSERT  INTO db1.HtUser (firstName, lastName, email, [username])
SELECT  firstName, lastName, email,
        'ch' + SUBSTRING(firstName,1,2) + SUBSTRING(lastname,1,3)
FROM    db2.HtUser
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into TABLEDIFF utility that comes with SQL Server 2005 and up ? Good examples can be found [here](http://www.replicationanswers.com/TableDiff2005.asp) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162843.aspx)

```
tablediff.exe utility features

Comparison between two tables from SQL Server instance. 
Row by row fast comparision. 
**Perform column level comparison.** 
Easily generate change script between production and development SQL server instances.
Log result can be captured as output file or database table.
Location:

tablediff.exe is available on SQL Server instance at 
"<DriveLetter>:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\COM\TableDiff.exe"

 <DriveLetter> is the hard drive where SQL Server instance is installed.
```